# Using :not to select all elements except inside box with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have an overlay that I want to hide on `mousedown` outside it.

Here is what I tried out but unfortunately `:not` selector is not working as I expected.

```
$('body:not(.overlay)').one('mousedown',function(){
        //hide overlay here
});
```

I also tried `$('* :not(.overlay)')` but same issue.

The overlay gets hidden even when clicking inside the overlay box

Comment: I am not aware of html structures. I am using xhtml btw..

Comment: @user01 he means what is the markup!

Comment: @xdazz: I m using Facelets with JSF 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on( "mousedown.hideoverlay", function(e){
    if( $(e.target).closest(".overlay").length === 0 ) { //overlay wasn't clicked.
        //hide overlay
        $(document).off("mousedown.hideoverlay");
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice use of closest() got me with that +1, though to avoid ambiguity should it not check for `<= 0` ?

Comment: Simple == condition should suffice, would be a little bit faster than checking for type equality.

Comment: Thanks this works. but why didn't my selector worked if you could clarify please ?

Comment: @user01 o.v. Has just answered that part...look to his answer

Answer (score 2):

Your selector `body:not(.overlay)` matches the body element if it doesn't have a class `overlay`, I'm assuming what you meant was its descendant without the class `overlay`:

```
$('body :not(.overlay)'); //note the space - descendant selector
```

The problem with such an assignment is that it matches too many elements (in particular, parents of selected elements). Tehnically, even clicking on any container `div` would match the selector, [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/eJCZn/2/). This happens because even clicks on elements with `overlay` class continue propagating up the DOM.

I agree with other suggestions here i.e. it's appropriate to listen to all clicks and *do nothing* if the selector doesn't match, however preventing event propagation on them could interfere with the rest of the page's logic.

I'd rather advocate an approach where there is an explicit subset of "overlayable" items that could be clicked on - and filter them with `:not(.overlay)` selector:

```
$('.some-generic-container-name:not(.overlay)')...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the .not() function: http://api.jquery.com/not/ . It specifically removes elements from a selected group which is probably the problem you are getting here. Saves having to do complex if's etc to solve this

```
$('*').not('.overlay').on('mousedown', function(){
    alert("here");
});
```

#### Edit

Heh, Didn't read the question fully:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e){
   var target = $(e.target);
   if(!target.parents().hasClass('overlay') && !target.hasClass('overlay')){
      // hide stuff
   }
});
```

Edit: I prefer to use click here (Dunno why):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
   var target = $(e.target);
   if(!target.parents().hasClass('overlay') && !target.hasClass('overlay')){
      // hide stuff
   }
});
```

It just looks nicer in my opinion, call me weird...

Comment: how do you call jQuery methods on an event object?

Comment: @undefined Millionth edit and I think it's actually correct now...too early for this :(